# Using an ArcGIS Online Web Experience in Offline Mode

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-online

I want to use an ArcGIS Online Web Experience in an environment where there is no internet connection. I installed the ArcGIS Experience Builder Developer Edition, created a new application, ran the server through node.js, specified the URL to my ArcGIS Online and added the Client ID given in the application. After those steps, I imported the Web Experience page from my account and downloaded it to my local disc. The content of the downloaded file is below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz4vP.png)

When I start the server, I can reach this Web Experience through https://localhost:3001/. However, when I cut the internet connection, data inside the page disappears.
Is there a way to use a Web Experience fully offline? Like embedding gdb data or shapefiles directly into the config.js file rather than using hosted feature services. Or do I need to adopt a completely different approach?
Thanks in advance,
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to run ArcGIS Experience Builder offline, you must make changes so that the application can find them locally (JSAPI) (by default it will look for JSAPIs from the ArcGIS site) (In the previous post of @Noah is the Offline installation process).

The normal workflow for web viewers is use ArcGIS Online (AGOL) (internet required), or ArcGIS Enterprise (AGE) services; if you are in a local environment without internet access you can use map services that have referenced data from an Enterprise Geodatabase (Oracle, SQL Server or PostgreSQL), a FGDB (File Geodatabase), Shapefile, or hosted features in the Data Store from the ArcGIS Enterprise. Its the ArcGIS GIS Server that works as an intermediary, reading, interpreting and presenting the data in a service that is later used by a web viewer (ArcGIS Enterprise can be used in both online and offline environments).

Its not feasible to directly read items such as a FGDB without first publishing it as a service in AGOL or AGE. I recommend you to ask questions on the [Esri Community](https://community.esri.com/), it is the "specialized" community in ArcGIS and you can have more exposure for queries like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation about Experience Builder offline:
https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/install-guide/#offline-install

You will want to ensure that all resources are accessible offline. I'd recommend watching the network traffic to see where the resources are coming from, and change them to be accessible offline.